# updating a belief distribution given a measurment

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robotics, kalman-filter, bayesian-networks

If you are given:

- a probability distribution that a robot sensor detects an object , given that it is in a location p(z|x).
- prior probabilities that the robot is in any location
- An actual observation made by the robots sensor

and asked to update the probability distribution given this observation, what method would one use?

I am not sure if i should be using a bayes filter, kalman filter, or if i am over thinking this problem.

as an example:

if a robot can move along a the number line from 1-7, with a standing poll at x=4.  The robot can tell if the poll is to its left, right or in front of it (z=-1,1,0 respectfully).

```
p(z|x)  x=1   x=2  x=3  x=4  x=5  x=6  x=7  
z= -1   0     0    0    .25  .5   .5   .5  
z = 0  ...  (its an example so im leaving this off)  
z = 1  ...  

( = 1) = 0.1; ( = 2) = 0.2; ( = 3) = 0.2; ( = 4) = 0.2;
( = 5) = 0.2; ( = 6) = 0.1; ( = 7) = 0.0
```

than the robot sensor outputs z=-1  .  What method would i use to update the above table

Comment: Your problem statement is basically the description of a particle filter.  The "prior probabilities that the robot is in any location" are the particles.  The "actual observation" plus "the probability distribution given..." is how you do the updates.

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert in this but i have seen a similar kind of topic discussed in this link. i hope this mighthelp you. good luck.
http://bilgin.esme.org/BitsAndBytes/KalmanFilterforDummies